# How to implement joint exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, applications

A Random Set is a set-valued RV, i.e. a map $X:\Omega\to\mathcal{C}$ from a probability space $(\Omega,\Lambda,P)$ to the family of closed sets $\mathcal{C}\ni X_1,\dots,X_\ell$ generating a $\sigma-$algebra $\Lambda$ from the elementals $\omega\in\Omega$, and such RV takes set values:

$$X^{-1}(K)=\{ \omega|X(\omega)\cap K\neq\emptyset \},$$

where $K$ is a closet set called the "trap" or structuring set.

I'm trying to compute the probability of some set event $X_j$, and for this I'm using the Law of Total Pobability:
$$
P(X=X_j)=\sum_{i\in\{1,\dots,\ell\}\setminus j} P(X_j, X_i).
$$
I'm not sure how to implement the joint probability of the sum in terms of the exponential distribution. What I'm trying to do by analogy to what one can do for conditional probability is:
$$
P(X_j)=\sum_{i\in\{1,\dots,\ell\}\setminus j} \lambda \exp(-\lambda |X_j\cap X_i|).
$$
However, I'm not sure if this is the correct manner to compute such probability, and how can I generalize it to more than one RV. I'd like to know specific considerations (and where can I see them) to verify such computations without (conceptual) errors.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks @Masacroso, I'm really confused. I'll rewrite the question in terms of RVs. I'll be accepting any observation so as to understand well what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What is the probability model?  To say "$X_i$ are sets (DNA strings)" does not help define the problem in a way that can be solved.  What is their assumed structure and why do they have subscripts of $i$?

Comment: @Michael, I have edited the question by entering more information. Do you think I provide better information about the problem? Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: I think you have a random object $X$ that can take $L$ possible values $$X=\left\{\begin{array} 
x_1& \mbox{ with prob $p_1$}\\ 
x_2&\mbox{ with prob $p_2$}\\
...&...\\
x_L & \mbox{ with prob $p_L$}
\end{array}\right.$$
The connect exponentials is unclear, and the equation you give as an analogy is mysterious.

Comment: You're right. Please, can you show me how to arrive at the right expression, instead the  mysterious one?

Comment: The "$1$" in my above comment should have been "$x_1$." Anyway.  If you are trying to compute $P[X=x_j]$ then the answer is $p_j$, by the definition of the random variable.